How to avoid `scalar` of empty array returning `undef`?
Related to How do I return an empty array / array of length 0 in perl? a bit, but still different:
While developing some new code I had a UNITCHECK that compares two "arrays":
One being defined as constant list, while the other is the result of a subroutine call.
Initially both array are empty, but scalar returns undef for the empty list, while it returns 0 for the subroutine result.
I don't understand the problem, but like to make scalar return 0 for the empty list as well.
The initial error message making me aware was:

Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference ...

So I examined it in the debugger:
NamedFlags::CODE(0xf5da48)(lib/NamedFlags.pm:95):
95:             unless (scalar(@{(FLAG_NAMES)}) == scalar(_FLAGS_ENUM->names()));
  DB<1> x scalar(@{(FLAG_NAMES)})
0  undef
  DB<2> x FLAG_NAMES
  empty array
  DB<3> x @{(FLAG_NAMES)}
  empty array
  DB<4> x scalar @{(FLAG_NAMES)}
0  undef
  DB<5> x _FLAGS_ENUM->names()
  empty array
  DB<7> x scalar _FLAGS_ENUM->names()
0  0
  DB<8>

The initial definition of FLAG_NAMES is use constant FLAG_NAMES => ().
Maybe the issue is equivalent to this.
  DB<8> x scalar ()
Not enough arguments for scalar at (eval 12)[/usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/perl5db.pl:732] line 2, near "scalar ()"
  DB<9> x scalar (())
0  undef

Assigning the empty list to an array variable solved the issue, but if possible I'd like to avoid that:
  DB<10> x scalar (@x = ())
0  0

Equivalent, but reproducible debugger session:
% perl -de1

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> use strict

  DB<2> use warnings

  DB<3> use constant E => ()

  DB<11> sub e() { my @a = E; return @a }

  DB<12> x scalar e
0  0
  DB<13> x scalar E
0  undef
  DB<14>


Can you please add a [mre]?

@UWindl You're an experienced SO user, you should know that posting code is something that you always do when asking a question.

For what it's worth, using scalar() with == is redundant, because == imposes scalar context. And using array dereferencing brackets around a constant is wrong, because the constant is not an array reference. undef == 0 will be true, but will give an undef warning.

The behavior of list constants is documented: https://perldoc.perl.org/constant#List-constants

@TLP I thought it's "obvious enough" that both variants return an "empty array", but scalar treats them differently. I'll try to provide a reproducible debugger session.

@clamp You mean "A constant with no values evaluates to undef in scalar context."? Well, I didn't read that, because it's somewhat unexpected. It's too long ago, but isn't even the empty list different from nilin LISP?

@U.Windl To be able to tell someone how to do something different/correctly, it is vital to know how they did it in the first place. Now you've just boiled down the question to a rather uninteresting "well, how does the constants pragma work?" This is an XY-problem, and the simple solution is probably "dont use constants".

If the recommendation is "don't use constants", then I tend to ask: "*Why did they implement it like that?" (if it's such a pain to use).

Use scalar( () = FLAG_NAMES ).

Sounds you have use constant FLAG_NAMES => ( ); or equivalent.
If so, FLAG_NAMES is equivalent to a sub that returns nothing.
You are treating it as a sub that returns a reference to an empty array, but it's actually returning undef.[1] Under use strict; and use warnings;, this should be noisy and fatal.
To count how many scalar expression LIST returns in list context, you can use scalar( () = LIST ).


The docs warn against relying on the value returned in scalar context as it may change.


scalar( () = EXPR ) works, but it looks quite strange to those who are not deeply into Perl; I find scalar(my @dummy = EXPR) more readable, even though it's less efficient, most likely.

@U. Windl If you worried about readability, scalar( my @dummy = EXPR ) isn't any better. I'd even argue it's worse because it's not idiomatic. If you want something more readable, how about the self-descriptive my $count = () = EXPR;, or sub count { 0+@_ }

It's always a question of readability vs. "geekiness": True geeks would avoid any elements that aren't strictly required, while that might make the code hard to read for non-geeks. I try to find my balance between those two (while admitting that I'm not always consistent).

I don't understand why use constant FLAG_NAMES => ( ) would create a constant "returning nothing": If I use x () in the debugger it says "empty array"; is "empty array" the same as nothing? Definitely it's not undef. Can you explain in detail?


Because that's what it's documented to do. 2) Functions can't return arrays, only a number of scalars. So it couldn't possibly return an array. 3) () is not an empty array. Parens do nothing but change precedence. Well, () is a special case. Since "nothing" is not normally valid code. But it becomes valid code when surrounded by parens. Nothing returns nothing. (Or undef in scalar context, since you can't return nothing in scalar context.)


OK, I wasn't aware of that. So "nothing" is not "undef" (rather confusing, because I thought that "undef" means nothing. If () actually is the syntax for "nothing", I wonder why I am allowed to use constant C => ();, or is there any use for such?

Re "So "nothing" is not "undef"", Correct. When you are returning a scalar that's undef, you are returning more than zero scalars, not zero of them. my @a = ( ); say 0+@a; my @b = ( undef ); say 0+@b;

Re "I wonder why I am allowed to use constant C => ();", Why wouldn't you be allowed???

I used "allowed" in the sense of "no warning": If that does not make any sense, why doesn't Perl warn about that?

Again, why would it???

Edit: didn't find the answer
I'm going with syntax error. Looks like you're doing the "give me an array from this thing" twice with @{(FLAG_NAMES)}.
perl -E 'use constant FLAG_NAMES => ("a", "b"); say @{(FLAG_NAMES)}'


gives nothing, but
perl -E 'use constant FLAG_NAMES => ("a", "b"); say (FLAG_NAMES)' 
ab

gives you what you expect, so scalar is working just fine
perl -E 'use constant FLAG_NAMES => ("a", "b"); say scalar (FLAG_NAMES)'
2

The @{...} is what you would do to get a list out of an arrayref, but you've already created a list with the (...)
Sorry, you're not wrong.
perl -E 'use constant FLAG_NAMES => (); say scalar (FLAG_NAMES)' 


gives nothing, but what you were testing does give you 0 (and why I do not know)
perl -E 'use constant FLAG_NAMES => ("a", "b"); say scalar @{(FLAG_NAMES)}'
0


Add use strict to your last example.

Sorry if the question was not as clear as I had thought it to be; see the added debugger session.
